# Does a destructor call itself when an object passed as a parameter goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, reference, destructor, operator-keyword

I am using a static variable to keep track of the number of instances of an object. I am getting some unpredictable behavior with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class comp{
private:
 int a;
 int b;

 public:
  friend comp &operator+(comp, comp);
   static int c;
   comp(int, int);
   comp();
   ~comp();
   int getA();
   int getB();
   void print() const;
};

int comp::c = 0;

comp::~comp() {

    c--;
    cout << "destroying comp of " << a << ", " << b << ", count after decrement is  " << c << endl;
    }


comp &operator+(comp A, comp B){
  comp C = comp(A.a + B.a, A.b + B.b);
  cout << "in +, count is " << comp::c << endl;
  return C;
}

comp::comp(int A, int B){
  a = A;
  b = B;
  c++;
}

comp::comp(){
  a = 0; b = 0; c++;
}

int comp::getA(){
  return a;
}

int comp::getB(){
  return b;
}

void comp::print() const{
  cout << a << ", " << b << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << comp::c << endl;
    comp A = comp(3,4);
    cout << comp::c << endl;
    comp B = comp(4,5);
    cout << comp::c << endl;
    A + B;
    A.print();
    B.print();
    cout << "About to exit main, c is: " << comp::c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is this:

```
0
1
2
in +, count is 3
destroying comp of 7, 9, count after decrement is  2
destroying comp of 3, 4, count after decrement is  1
destroying comp of 4, 5, count after decrement is  0
3, 4
4, 5
About to exit main, c is: 0
destroying comp of 4, 5, count after decrement is  -1
destroying comp of 3, 4, count after decrement is  -2
```

This behavior is being caused by the line

```
 A + B;
```

My best guess as to what is happening is that when the objects are passed in as parameters to a function, the constructor is not being called (so c is not being incremented), but when the function goes out of scope, the destructor is called. This leads to a net loss in count.

However, the overloaded operator+ passed variables by references. Wouldn't this prevent the parameters from going out of scope and the destructor being called?

The output is the same regardless of whether the overloaded + operator is declared as:

```
friend comp &operator+(comp, comp);
```

or

```
friend comp operator+(comp, comp);
```

This leads me confused as to why and how the destructor is being called.

One last question: is it good practice, when using overloaded operators, to pass by reference rather than by value? If so, why?

Thanks!

EDIT:
It appears as if I was confusing the syntax a bit. I thought that

```
friend comp &operator+(comp, comp);
```

was passing the parameters by reference instead of

```
friend comp operator+(comp&, comp&);
```

Excuse my noobish question, but could someone explain what the "&" operator does before a function name? If I understand correctly, "&" is the reference operator and gives the address given a variable. However, if one would want to return a reference, the "*" operator would be appropriate. For instance:

```
int *a()
```

The above function signature returns a memory address that points to an int.

```
int &a()
```

What would that function signature return?

Answer (score 4):

You are not accounting for objects created by default, compiler generated copy constructor. Define one, count the objects created there and the math will work out.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when you get objects as parameters, you make a copy of them. And that's that copy which will be destructed at the end of the scope.
In order to avoid that, you should pass them by reference:

```
comp operator+(comp& a, comp& b);
```

The `&` in the return type is of the return value, i.e.  `C` in your code. And this is bad, because you send a reference to a variable created locally, which will be destroyed at the end of the scope.

Comment: You still need a copy constructor to return the result. So you will be missing this one copy operation from the equation. My answer still holds ;).

Comment: As OP states, the problem exists (with varying severity, I would suspect) regardless of whether the parameters are passed by value or by reference. That is because the *real* cause is the lack of overriden copy constructor.

Comment: Actually, the problem no longer exists when I pass by reference. I was confusing syntax. I thought comp &operator+ was pass by reference. Now that I switched it to  comp operator+(comp &a, comp &b), the code works. I'll still try adding a copy constructor to it

Comment: btw, it should be const reference. (so `comp operator + (const comp&A, const comp&B)`).

Comment: @user2445455 However, if you fix the undefined behaviour (read: evil bug that can't even be reliable reproduced) of returning a reference to a local variable, by returning by value, the problem will re-surface.

Comment: @user2445455, the problem goes away when changing parameters passed in to references and keeping the result as a value probably because RVO (return value optimization) kicks in.